# informix DB with RobotFramework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, informix

I am trying to connect to informix DB from Robotframework script running on Mac. I have installed Robotframework-Database-Library[1.0.1] from http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/.

tried to install Informix DB per https://wiki.python.org/moin/Informix. Ran into issue

> **error: Can't find esql. Please set INFORMIXDIR correctly.**

tried to install mxODBC using python. still running into error

I have installed egenix-mx-base-3.2.9-py2.7_ucs2-macosx-10.5-x86_64-prebuilt as this is precondition. Tried to verify the mx-base using.

> **$ pip install egenix-mx-base 
>   Requirement already satisfied: egenix-mx-base in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.**

Then tried to install egenix-mxodbc-3.3.6-py2.7_ucs2-macosx-10.4-fat-prebuilt.

> msuresh$ python setup.py install 
>   running install
>   found usable build data file 'build/build-py2.7_ucs2.pck'
>   prebuilt archive found: skipping the build process and loading the prebuilt archive
>   setting platform to 'macosx-10.4-fat'
>   adjusting distutils platform string from 'macosx-10.13-x86_64' to 'macosx-10.4-fat'
>   restoring build data from a previous build run
>   loaded build data for platform 'macosx-10.4-fat'
>   running install_lib
>   writing byte-compilation script '/var/folders/dc/nwlkjl0129d3qm1j8m5czmgsnkqkf_/T/tmpRNEu3H.py'
>   /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 -O /var/folders/dc/nwlkjl0129d3qm1j8m5czmgsnkqkf_/T/tmpRNEu3H.py
>   removing /var/folders/dc/nwlkjl0129d3qm1j8m5czmgsnkqkf_/T/tmpRNEu3H.py
>   running install_data
>   running install_egg_info
>   Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/egenix_mxodbc-3.3.6-py2.7.egg-info
>   Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/egenix_mxodbc-3.3.6-py2.7.egg-info

But on trying to verify mxodbc --> does through me error.

> **>>> import mx.ODBC.Manager
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "mx/ODBC/Manager/__init__.py", line 48, in 
>   ImportError: None of the supported ODBC managers unixODBC, iODBC or DataDirect could be imported: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/ODBC/unixODBC/mxODBC.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>           /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/ODBC/unixODBC/mxODBC.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
>           /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/ODBC/unixODBC/mxODBC.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper, dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/ODBC/iODBC/mxODBC.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>           /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/ODBC/iODBC/mxODBC.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
>           /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/ODBC/iODBC/mxODBC.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper, No module named DataDirect**

.. Any help to get informix connection via Robotframework would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you walked through the installation procedure on the [egenix-mxodbc](https://pypi.org/project/egenix-mxodbc/) page?

Comment: Yes, I have installled egenix-mx-base-3.2.9-py2.7_ucs2-macosx-10.5-x86_64-prebuilt, then tried to install egenix-mx-base-3.2.9-py2.7_ucs2-macosx-10.5-x86_64-prebuilt.  Tried to verify the mx-base using --> $ pip install egenix-mx-base
Requirement already satisfied: egenix-mx-base in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.  But  on trying to verify mxodbc --> does through me error. > **
ImportError: None of the supported ODBC managers unixODBC, iODBC or DataDirect could be imported: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/ODBC/unixODBC/mxODBC.so, 2): no suitable image found. Did find:**

Comment: Can you add the information to the question itself, instead of posting as a comment. This will allows you more formatting options and keeps all your information in one place.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. i hope i have made the issue clear

Comment: On the [Robotframework-Database-Library](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/) going to the linked [A Database API Specification 2.0 Python Module](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces) page you'll find Informix under [General Purpose Databases]( https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces#General_Purpose_Database_Systems). Under the section  for [mxODBC](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Informix#mxODBC) you'll find the following note: `The Informix ODBC drivers needed for mxODBC are included in the Informix CSDK.` Do you have this installed?

Comment: msuresh$ python setup.py build_ext
running build_ext
sh: /usr/informix/bin/esql: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/informix/bin/esql: No such file or directory
error:
Can't find esql. Please set INFORMIXDIR correctly.  -- I am running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to download and install the Informix Client SDK from [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=ifxdl)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself

Comment: The Client SDK is a pre-requisite for the mxODBC driver, as per **A. Kootstra** above. I was just sharing where to get it, because IBM's website is terrible. I'm not really sure what more you want me to add?

Comment: You can add that as a comment to the question. Otherwise, elebarate more in the answer that y this sdk and and what is this for....?....

Comment: I can't add that as a comment because I don't have enough reputation.